# MongoDB: can sort and limit take advantage of shard keys?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have a collection that is sharded and indexed by the "height" field. Would following query avoid hitting multiple shards?

```
db.collection.find().sort({height:-1}).limit(1)
```

p.s. Atlas requires a paid tier for sharded collections, so have not been able to try it to look at the query plan

[EDIT] I upgraded my Atlas plan to analyze the query plan. This is the query plan:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.canonical_blocks.find().sort({height:-1}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1",
                    "connectionString" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017",
                    "serverInfo" : {
                        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
                        "port" : 27017,
                        "version" : "4.4.6",
                        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
                    },
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "indexer1.canonical_blocks",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        
                    },
                    "queryHash" : "2933A452",
                    "planCacheKey" : "2933A452",
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "height" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "height_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                    "height" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : true,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "backward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "height" : [
                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
        "port" : 27016,
        "version" : "4.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1625625304, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1625625304, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"kOk5Oxr3S0xQMhSbesuLlZpL9dQ="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6981961109108424710")
        }
    }
}
```

The "SINGLE_SHARD" seems to confirm that a single shard was targeted. But, all documents are on the same shard atm, so may not be a reliable confirmation.

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.canonical_blocks.getShardDistribution()

Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0 at atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017
 data : 1KiB docs : 21 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 1KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 21

Totals
 data : 1KiB docs : 21 chunks : 1
 Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 52B
```

[EDIT 2] I updated the chunk size to a small size (1 MB) and inserted tons of data, so that now there are documents on two shards:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.canonical_blocks.getShardDistribution()

Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0 at atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017
 data : 3MiB docs : 60497 chunks : 6
 estimated data per chunk : 512KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 10082

Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1 at atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017
 data : 6.22MiB docs : 125594 chunks : 7
 estimated data per chunk : 911KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 17942

Totals
 data : 9.22MiB docs : 186091 chunks : 13
 Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-0 contains 32.5% data, 32.5% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 52B
 Shard atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1 contains 67.49% data, 67.49% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 52B
```

The query plan for `db.collection.find().sort({height:-1}).limit(1)`:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.collection.find().sort({height:-1}).limit(1).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1",
                    "connectionString" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017",
                    "serverInfo" : {
                        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
                        "port" : 27017,
                        "version" : "4.4.6",
                        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
                    },
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "indexer1.collection",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "EOF"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
        "port" : 27016,
        "version" : "4.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1625643987, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1625643987, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"Bv/1hKYaFxOP34lGkik5Y7DExiY="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6981961109108424710")
        }
    }
}
```

Query plan for `db.collection.find()` also indicates "SINGLE_SHARD":

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.collection.find().explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1",
                    "connectionString" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-1/atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-00.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net:27017",
                    "serverInfo" : {
                        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-01-02.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
                        "port" : 27017,
                        "version" : "4.4.6",
                        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
                    },
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "indexer1.collection",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "EOF"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "atlas-1ewlwe-shard-00-01.jy3fd.mongodb.net",
        "port" : 27016,
        "version" : "4.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : "72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7"
    },
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1625644078, 3),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1625644078, 3),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"nH5crYWxK8COuZubSTrXsGMOfl0="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6981961109108424710")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a sharded cluster on a local machine: see [deploy a sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/).

Comment: I would assume `"indexBounds" : {"height" : ["[MaxKey, MinKey]"]}` indicates that it would target all shards

Comment: Thank you @prasad_, ran into some issues with local cluster and ended up doing it on Atlas. Currently confused that a query that does not filter by the shard key (height), also mentions "SINGLE_SHARD" in the query plan.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ah thanks, looking into more documentation to figure out what these pieces of query plan mean.

Comment: This is explained at this topic [How mongos handles the query modifiers?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers) - the query modifiers `sort` and `limit`.  In summary, your query will hit all shards.